# How to convert Html table to xls (excel)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `FileSaver.js` where I need to convert HTML table to xls using `AngularJS`.

Works fine with all browser but issue with iOS device.

Any alternate solution or any other plugin that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

The following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/umidjons/352da2a4209691d425d4) at Github shows you how to export an HTML table to Microsoft Excel.

```
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
    var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('MyCtrl',function(Excel,$timeout){
      $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
            $scope.exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'sheet name');
            $timeout(function(){location.href=$scope.fileData.exportHref;},100); // trigger download
    }
});
```

And then call it for example like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="exportToExcel('#table1')">       
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> Export to Excel
</button>
```